# Pass all filenames in a folder to a bash script, adding special appendix

Tags: linux, bash, sh, batch-processing

I want to use the whiteboardCleaner.md script (https://gist.github.com/lelandbatey/8677901) on a several files, so I have to pass it two filenames at once, the input and the output ones.

The script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
convert "$1" -morphology Convolve DoG:15,100,0 -negate -normalize -blur 0x1 -channel RBG -level 60%,91%,0.1 "$2"
```

Normally I have to run it like

```
./whiteboard input.jpg input-processed.jpg
```

But how do I loop it over all the files in a folder?

Comment: Have you tried finding examples of scripts that loop over all the files in a folder?

Comment: I have, but i did not get how do i append something to the filename? This is the main problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.jpg do
  convert "$file" \
  -morphology Convolve DoG:15,100,0 \
  -negate \
  -normalize \
  -blur 0x1 \
  -channel RBG \
  -level 60%,91%,0.1 \
  "${file}-processed"
done
```